# Configure Nginx to serve web app and backend php/slim api

Tags: php, nginx, slim

I am trying to get a php/slim app to work using nginx (its the winecellar bootstrap app but this could relate to any php app).

I have the web app located at /home/paul/winecellar/bootstrap
and the php/slim app located at /home/paul/winecellar/api and I wanted to configure the server to treat them as two separate entities (i.e. the api folder should not actually be inside the bootstrap folder)

I need to get the web app to be served from / which I can achieve, but I cannot make the api work from /api/ (e.g. /api/wines)

I would expect to be able to use localhost/api/wines in a browser (or indeed the web app) to GET the list of wines returned by the api, but its a 404 error. Below is one of the many configs I have tried without success.

```
server {
    listen   80; 
    root /home/paul/winecellar/bootstrap;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location /api/index.php {
        alias /home/paul/winecellar/api/;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
          return 404;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        rewrite ^/(.*).php/(.*) /$1/$2;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}}
```

I don't know why its not serving the app.

Comment: What do you get in your /var/log/nginx/access.log with your 404 error ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I posted the question. I'll have to try it again, thanks for the suggestion.